# Socket hex com checksum

Tags: php, socket, hexadecimal, bit, checksum

Estou desenvolvendo um socket de comunicação entre um rastreador e o servidor.
O socket está em perfeito funcionamento.

Meu problema está com a comunicação na hora de checar o checksum.
O dispositivo manda uma mensagem que vai de 0 a 200 bytes para o servidor que convertendo para hexadecimal da: `2929b1000725cadc610ce80d` que transformo num array que fica assim:

`{["29","29","b1","0","7","25","ca","dc","61","c","e8","d"]}`, a 10º posição do array é o checksum `e8` que é calculado com uma soma XOR, assim:
`29 Xor 29 Xor b1 Xor 00 Xor 07 Xor 25 Xor ca Xor dc Xor 61 Xor 0c = e8`.

Logo desenvolvi o seguinte trecho para realizar essa soma:

```
// transformando a 1ª posição em bit
$checksum = pack('H*',$data[0]);
// correndo o array
for ($i = 1; $i < count($data)-2; $i++) {
  // Fazendo a soma XOR 
  $checksum ^= pack('H*',$data[$i]);
}
return $checksum;
```

onde `$data` é o array que mostrei acima.
O resultado que esta dando é `d7`;

*Obs. os valores que mostrei são de `print_r` que dei nas variáveis.

O que está errado?

Coloquei o script para rodar e notei que ele está dando irregularidade no resultado.

```
01-12-17 03:33:38pm Connection from 186.227.156.12:18747
 RECV -- {["29","29","b1","0","7","25","ca","dc","61","c","e8","d"]}
 IMEI -- {37749297}
01-12-17 03:33:38pm CheckSUM: cd
01-12-17 03:33:48pm Connection from 186.227.156.12:18747
 RECV -- {["29","29","b1","0","7","25","ca","dc","61","c","e8","d"]}
 IMEI -- {37749297}
01-12-17 03:33:48pm CheckSUM: 6b
01-12-17 03:33:58pm Connection from 186.227.156.12:18747
 RECV -- {["29","29","b1","0","7","25","ca","dc","61","c","e8","d"]}
 IMEI -- {37749297}
01-12-17 03:33:58pm CheckSUM: 6b
01-12-17 03:34:08pm Connection from 186.227.156.12:18747
 RECV -- {["29","29","b1","0","7","25","ca","dc","61","c","e8","d"]}
 IMEI -- {37749297}
01-12-17 03:34:08pm CheckSUM: 6b
01-12-17 03:34:17pm Connection from 186.227.156.12:18747
 RECV -- {["29","29","b1","0","7","25","ca","dc","61","c","e8","d"]}
 IMEI -- {37749297}
01-12-17 03:34:17pm CheckSUM: 6b
01-12-17 03:34:17pm Connection to 186.227.156.12:18747 closed
Handle ...
01-12-17 03:34:20pm Connection from 186.227.156.12:23463
 Interact ...
01-12-17 03:34:22pm Connection from 186.227.156.12:23463
 RECV -- {["29","29","b1","0","7","25","ca","dc","61","c","e8","d"]}
 IMEI -- {37749297}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao ler a documentação do PHP a respeito da função XOR, notei que a linguagem não faz distinção de string, decimal ou hexadecimal. E como já notei em diversos casos, calcular em decimal acaba sendo até mais fácil para nos. Por isso substitui pelo seguinte trecho:

```
function checkSum($data){
// Realizo a conversão de Hexadecimal para Decimal:
$checksum = hexdec($data[0]);
// Corro o array para calcular.
for ($i = 1; $i < count($data)-2; $i++) {
  // faço a soma xor convertendo para decimal
  $checksum ^= hexdec($data[$i]);
  // Uso minha função para registrar o log em arquivo.
  printLog(null, date("d-m-y h:i:sa") . " - " .$data[$i]." Somando XOR: ".dechex($checksum));

}
// Retorno convertendo para hexadecimal:
return dechex($checksum);
```

}

Desse jeito funcionou e está rodando perfeitamente.